# Yii2: How to catch yii\db\IntegrityException globally

Tags: sql, exception, yii2

I have several models with related tables, which would throw a yii\db\IntegrityException when i try to delete a record.

How can i catch just this exception globally, redirect the user to an error page telling him that this record can't be deleted due to "related data exisiting" and offer a "back" button to the action where he tried to delete the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to friendly help of the Yii IRC chat i came up with the following solution:

Create a custom base mode:

```
class MyActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    ...
}
```

Herein i overwrite the original

```
actionDelete($id)
```

like

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    try {
        ... try to delete the record ...
    } catch (db\IntegrityExceptyion $e) {
        ... send to error page ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Am also facing the same problem, can you give more details

Comment: Which details do you need?

Comment: am also facing the same problem, i need a code which you used to solve this problem\